# OkHttp Bad Encoding

Tags: android, okhttp

I've got this XML (I don't control it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
    <test>
        <text name="Café" />
   </test>
```

But it doesn't return the correct result:

> Caf�

My code is the basic of example: http://square.github.io/okhttp/

headers request return this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml
Last-Modified: Mon, 08 Aug 2016 02:41:08 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "1bbb4511ef1d11:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 08 Aug 2016 02:42:45 GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use **encoding="utf-8"**
go to settings >> editor >> file encodings and change the IDE encoding and Project encoding to **utf-8**.

**ex image**:

[image: ex image]

Comment: It is already well

Answer (score 0):

The server is responding without an encoding so OkHttp is using the default hardcoded UTF-8. OkHttp will ignore the XML encoding tag if you are reading it as a String.

Specifically é is 2 bytes in UTF-8 and 1 byte in iso-8859-1.

You have three options

1) Change the file to be encoded with UTF-8 and change the XML encoding attribute. Ideally (but optionally) specify the charset UTF-8 in the response headers.

2) Leave the file as iso-latin-1 but return the charset in the response Content-Type header.

3) If you don't have control of the file or headers, then you should be reading it as a sequence of bytes that you provide to an XML library for it to process using the encoding header.

Comment: edited with headers